# Change the default caption of a label with MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a label on my MS Access main form that needs to display the save location of an export file.  I have an [Edit] button that when clicked brings up a file dialog box and allows the user to select a folder to export to.  Once the folder is selected the label caption changes to the location of the folder that the user selected.  This works excellently.  My only issue, is that when the DB is closed and reopened the label caption is back to whatever the original caption was (in this instance lets say it just says TEST).  I would like to have it so that when the label caption is changed, it stays that way unless the user clicks the [Edit] button and changes the location again.  Below is the VBA code that I am using.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Sub SetFileLocation()
    Dim Ret

    strUserName = Environ("UserName")

    strPath = "C:\documents and settings\" & strUserName & "\Desktop"


    '~~> Specify your start folder here
    Ret = BrowseForFolder(strPath)

    Forms.frmmainform.lblFolderLocation.Caption = strFolderLocation



End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
     'Function purpose:  To Browser for a user selected folder.
     'If the "OpenAt" path is provided, open the browser at that directory
     'NOTE:  If invalid, it will open at the Desktop level

    Dim ShellApp As Object

     'Create a file browser window at the default folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)



     'Set the folder to that selected.  (On error in case cancelled)
    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0
Debug.Print BrowseForFolder
strFolderLocation = BrowseForFolder
Debug.Print strFolderLocation
     'Destroy the Shell Application
    Set ShellApp = Nothing

     'Check for invalid or non-entries and send to the Invalid error
     'handler if found
     'Valid selections can begin L: (where L is a letter) or
     '\\ (as in \\servername\sharename.  All others are invalid
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function

Invalid:
     'If it was determined that the selection was invalid, set to False
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

Comment: That would require modifying the form in design view. What you need to do is retrieve the 'last' item and set controls when form opens. This means saving data somewhere so that it can be retrieved.

Comment: I'd really prefer not to have to set up a table to store the data, would it be possible to store it in a control like a label?  I thought that I had done something similar in the past on a different project but I can seem to find it.

Comment: No. "Saving" in a label is changing Caption property and that requires design view and saving the modified design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although best way is storing value in some table you can save previous value in custom form property.
First create a form property (in immediate window):

```vb
CurrentProject.AllForms ("Your form name").Properties.Add "LastFolder", ""
```

Then save it in your sub like that

```vb
...
Me.lblFolderLocation.Caption = strFolderLocation
CurrentProject.AllForms("Your form name").Properties("LastFolder").Value = strFolderLocation
```

Then restore last value in Load event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.lblFolderLocation.Caption  = CurrentProject.AllForms("Your form name").Properties("LastFolder")
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked exactly how I wanted it to.  I didn't;t want to have to create a table with one record and be constantly editing that record.  This worked great, thanks for your help!